# « Il y y a de très bons exemples »

Tags: pronoms, usage, indications-de-lieu

Imaginez-vous le contexte suivant :

> Cette grammaire est très utile ; il y y a de très bons exemples.

En anglais, *il y y a* serait *in it there are*. Je crois que *il y y a* est une phrase correcte en français.

Et ma question est : quel *y*, le premier ou le second, est le *y* qui remplace *in it* ? Je crois que c'est le premier *y* qui le remplace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il est impossible d'avoir les deux *y* à la suite. La phrase que tu proposes n'est pas correcte. *Il y a...* étant une expression immuable, soit on la remplace par une autre expression exprimant la même chose, soit on exprime le lieu par autre chose que *y*.

- On remplace l'expression du lieu par autre chose que *y*, plusieurs possibilités sont envisageables, dont :

  > Cette grammaire est très utile ; il y a **là** de très bons exemples.
  >   Cette grammaire est très utile ; il y a **dans cet ouvrage** de très bons exemples.
- On n'utilise pas *il y a* et le *y* représente « un lieu» (la grammaire) :

  > Cette grammaire est très utile, on **y** trouve de très bons exemples.
  >   Cette grammaire est très utile, il s'**y** trouve de très bons exemples.

  Personnellement je préfère la deuxième solution proposée (éviter l'utilisation de *il y a*) mais les deux sont possibles et corrects.

Edit :
Je viens de trouver [cette explication](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/315.html) sur l'impossibilité de dire *il y y a*. Impossibilité grammaticale, même si la tournure  paraît logique. Bien que le raisonnement se fasse avec une langue étrangère (le finnois), il est compréhensible même si on ne parle pas le finnois.

Edit 2 :
Une recherche dans [google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22il%20y%20y%20a%22) montre quelques rares (2 940) occurences de *il y y a*, tous ces exemples datent d'avant le 20<sup>e</sup> siècle. Je ne sais pas si ce fut un jour considéré comme « acceptable » mais voici ce que dit Cyprien Ayer dans *[Grammaire comparée de la langue française](https://books.google.fr/books?id=48spAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA160&dq=%22il%20y%20y%20a%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22il%20y%20y%20a%22&f=falsehttps://books.google.fr/books?id=48spAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA160&dq=%22il%20y%20y%20a%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22il%20y%20y%20a%22&f=false)*  (1900) :

> Quand il y a se rapporte à un lieu déjà indiqué, on ne dit pas *il y y a* : *Je me suis retranché les dîners du roi*, il y a *trop de généraux et de princes* (Volt.).

De nos jours ce serait compris, certes, mais jamais employé par un francophone de l'hexagone. D'ailleurs une [recherche google](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=il%20y%20y%20a%20&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#q=%22il%20y%20y%20a%20%22&as_qdr=all&start=0) sur *il y y a*  renvoie très peu d'occurrences, la plupart étant vers des ouvrages anciens ou des sites ou forums peu soignés (typos probables) ou pour dire, comme  [le forum Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/forums/langue-francaise/Doublement-du-y-possible----Il-y-y-a/1117) sur la langue française :

> Le Y, qu'il soit adverbe ou pronom personnel, n'est jamais doublé.

Comment: Cependant j'ai vu et j'ai lu de nombreux exemples avec ce double _y_. Par exemple ici : _Cependant il y y a un point qui mérite réflexion, Socrate_. (Platon, _Œuvres complètes_, Les Belles Lettres, tome VII, 422a) Ou bien dans la langue moderne: _Bien sûr on y retrouve les restaurateurs habituels ou nouveaux. Bien sur il y y a l’animation phare des Etoiles d’Epicure chaque soir ainsi que des animations plus accessibles comme celle de l’atelier des chefs où vous pouvez vous initier gratuitement à une préparation culinaire_. (Bordeaux Gazette)

Comment: @User26328 Pas vraiment nombreux et la recherche montre plutôt que ce n'est pas utilisé.

Comment: C'est comme ça que j'apprends et que j’approfondis le français !